Duende Identity Server with Azure Kubernetes Service - State Error
We are trying to integrate Duende IdentityServer 7 in Azure Kubernetes Service and are using Data Protection as per below in ASP.NET
private static void RegisterDataProtection(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("IHD")
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionKeysContext>();   
}

At the backend, we have Azure SQL and we have verified storage of key in the database. For the purpose of scale, number of replica's are kept to 3 in Azure Kubernetes Service with 'hpa' to allow auto-scale to '10'.
For Ingress, we have added following annotations,
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/body-size: 1024m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 1024m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 128k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: 'on'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: '8'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      client_header_buffer_size 100k;
      large_client_header_buffers 4 100k;

Upon login process, we get the error:

Unable to unprotect the message.State

When we reduce the number of replicas to 1, the application runs correctly. This means the Duende IdentityServer can't load balance. We have verified the documentation here
This is running on .NET 6
What are we missing?

One potential issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3514 , https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26786 , https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28475  and finally https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53654
